# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'left')

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i'm trying to move the ball to right but i got this error :
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'left')
i tried to search but all the answers says that my code is correct

```js
var ballSpeed = 3;
var ballPosition = 0;
var ballTime = 1;
var ball = $('#ball');


function bT() {
  ballPosition = ballPosition + ballSpeed;
  ball.style.left = ballPosition + "px";
}

var ii =setInterval(bT, 1);
console.log(ii);
```

```css
.window{
  background-color: #00FFDD;
  height:100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}

#ball{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   
  <body>
<div class="window">
<div id="ball"></div>
</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ball = $('#ball');` is a jquery object - it doesn't have a `style` property.  Either use jquery to set the style or use `ball[0].style.left` to convert it back to a DOM node.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```js
var ballSpeed = 3;
var ballPosition = 0;
var ballTime = 1;
var ball = $('#ball');


function bT() {
  ballPosition = ballPosition + ballSpeed;
  ball.css('left', ballPosition);
}

var ii =setInterval(bT, 1);
console.log(ii);
```

```css
.window{
  background-color: #00FFDD;
  height:100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}

#ball{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   
  <body>
<div class="window">
<div id="ball"></div>
</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Modifying a JQuery element's style uses the `.css()` method, as outlined [here.](https://api.jquery.com/css/)